# Get value from JSON with RestTemplate in Spring application

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I try to parse value from JSON:

```
{"BTC_BCN":{"id":7,"last":"0.00000086","lowestAsk":"0.00000086","highestBid":"0.00000085","percentChange":"0.14666666","baseVolume":"368.86654762","quoteVolume":"498378738.00151879","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00000086","low24hr":"0.00000068"},"BTC_ETH":{"id":8,"last":"0.00003800","lowestAsk":"0.00003815","highestBid":"0.00003800","percentChange":"0.12326337","baseVolume":"34.17037464","quoteVolume":"955538.55551651","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00003883","low24hr":"0.00003221"}}
```

the values which I am interested in is `"id":8,"last":"0.00003800"`.
I have beans with RestTemplate:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```

and the one which ask website by API every 5 seconds

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
        return args -> {
            while(true)
            {
                BTC_Poloniex btc_poloniex = restTemplate.getForObject(
                        "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker", BTC_Poloniex.class);
                log.info(btc_poloniex.toString());
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            }           
        };
    }
```

and class to read the values:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BTC_Poloniex {
private BTC_BCN BTC_BCN;

public BTC_Poloniex() {}


public BTC_BCN getBTC_BCN() {
    return BTC_BCN;
}

public void setBTC_BCN(BTC_BCN btc_bcn)
{
    this.BTC_BCN = btc_bcn;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "BTC_Poloniex{" +
            "BTC_BCN=" + BTC_BCN +
            '}';
}
}
```

and class (which I think would be better if it were inner class)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BTC_BCN {
private long id;
private long last;
private long lowestAsk;

public BTC_BCN(){}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getLast() {
    return last;
}

public void setLast(long last) {
    this.last = last;
}

public long getLowestAsk() {
    return lowestAsk;
}

public void setLowestAsk(long lowestAsk) {
    this.lowestAsk = lowestAsk;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "BTC_BCN{" +
            " id='" + id + '\'' +
            " last'= " + last + '\'' +
            " lowestAsk'= " + lowestAsk + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

when I try to get these values I always have null

```
2018-01-12 14:00:14.829  INFO 18017 --- [           main] com.example.demo.BitbayApplication       : BTC_ETH{BTC_ETH=null}
```

why is that so? I can easily read simplier JSON but have problem with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution is to use Maps.
Sample is below.

Using this code you have access to every field from json :)

I hope that my solution is good enough for you :)

```
@Service
public class RestTemplateService {

@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;


public void getInfoFromPoloniex() {
    HashMap<String,Map> answer = restTemplate.getForObject("https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker",
            new HashMap<>().getClass());

    answer.values().forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.toString()));

    System.out.println(answer.get("BTC_GAME").getClass().toString());

    answer.get("BTC_GAME").keySet().stream().forEach(k -> System.out.println(k.toString()));


}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The variable defined in BTC_Poloniex class

```
private BTC_ETH BTC_ETH;
```

should be

```
    private BTC_ETH BTC_BCN;
```

because the json variable is

> BTC_BCN

this is should be same as variable name in json CLASS.

Comment: Well this JSON is much longer and also has:"BTC_ETH":{"id":148,"last":"0.08835958","lowestAsk":"0.08835960","highestBid":"0.08835958","percentChange":"0.00982377","baseVolume":"8642.21157715","quoteVolume":"98940.41129147","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.08989998","low24hr":"0.08420073"}. Even after changing name on BTC_BCN there is null

Comment: Edited answer and TC_Poloniex{BTC_BCN=null} ;/